# Is it possible to get dict {class: proba} from Decision Tree Classifier predict_proba()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

My model have more than 1k classes, and the method returns an array with probabilities, most of which are 0. I want to get top 3 predictions with their probabilities. How can i implement this?
I expect to get something like this:

```
[{class: proba}, {class: proba}, {class: proba}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's one sample:

```
{k: probs[k] for k in reversed(np.argpartition(probs,-3)[-3:])}
```

For a larger test set it'll grow into something like:

```
[{k: p[k] for k in reversed(np.argpartition(p,-3)[-3:])} for p in probs]
```

`argpartition` is like `argsort` but would only sort out 3 indices with largest values in this notation, saving you some complexity.

Or, if you don't mind importing torch just for this, it's got a nice `.topk()` method for tensors.